Question regarding the scanLRTS() function in spatstat
I hope all is well. I am hoping to evaluate for the presence of hotspots in my point pattern data using the scanLRTS() function. I have two questions regarding this function:

I am aware of the issue of multiple testing when attempting to compute significance values for the scan statistic for all spatial locations. I was wondering if it was prudent to use a multiple testing correction for the p values such as the bonferroni or holm method. I am aware of the scan.test() function, which assess for significant clustering via only looking at the highest value scan statistic, but this doesn't seem to allow one to identify the spatial location of significant hotspots within the pattern, only that there is statistically significant clustering. Please correct my interpretation if it is wrong.

I see in the book that the kernel bandwidth was used to approximate the r value for clustering. I'm wondering if it would instead be feasible to use the r value at which L(r) is maximized relative to CSR. This r value is significantly larger than the kernel bandwidth but I am curious about whether it would be more appropriate to look for clustering at larger scale clustering in the data. Alternatively I wonder if one could provide a range of r for scanLRTS and let the function select the most optimal r but I know this has impacts on the distribution of the scan statistic, so I am restricting to an a priori selection.


